# React-Native with FTP

Tags: react-native, npm, ftp

Is it possible to download/upload files and folders from FTP servers using react native? If yes, react-native-ftp package is the only one that I found which does not seem to work. Did anyone come across such a scenario?

Answer (score 0):

After doing a lot of research, it seems that react-native-ftp is the only package that works, and to download, use the below code:

FTP.downloadFile(`/--ftp-file-path`, RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath).then((res) => {console.log("res is", res) })

FYI - RNFS.ExternalStorageDirectoryPath = This is react-native-fs to access your phone's directory and also the path where your files will be downloaded. You can view this in your phone's internal storage.